# Packaging and distribution of node web-kit app done using Sails

Tags: exe, sails.js, node-webkit

I am new to **Node-webkit**. I have created a simple application and I would like to know how to package and distribute a node-webkit App done using **sails**. I want a complete **.exe** file which would help me install my application in any computers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [Packaging and Distribution](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps)
 for creating a executable file for a node webkit application